# How do I login in single user mode?

Tags: grub2, login

I needed to login through a single user mode in ubuntu 11.10 but don't know the changes I've to make in the grub command.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to to just select recovery mode in grub by hold down left <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting. Then Drop to root shell prompt.

If you need to write to files, select Remount first.

Comment: OK, but how do you get to the grub menu?  It doesn't appear by default.

Comment: Hold down left shift when booting.