# Lost control of root account, Ubuntu Server 11.10

Tags: 11.10, server, sudo, root

after I created a group, and put the root account in it, I lost control of it and now it's not root anymore.
Also I can't login with "root".
How can I revert this? Now there is no way I can use sudo commands. And I don't know what account the control has!

/etc/group looks like this:

```
root:x:0
...
developers:x:1004:thomas,website
```

Comment: I do not see a question ;-) but if you want to restore/reset etc sudo permissions you can do so from either grub or a live cd. The `root:x:0` is correct. Have a look at `/etc/sudoers`. Should contain `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/

Comment: /etc/sudoers and /etc/sudoers.d are both empty! And @Ysangkok it's the server edition so I cannot follow the tutorial since I cannot "try" it out!

Comment: @ThomasVersteeg: The desktop live CD will work even with your server installation. You can use KNOPPIX or SystemRescueCd too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being able to login as `root` (other than by using `sudo`) is normal; Ubuntu doesn't set a password for `root` by default.

The empty `/etc/sudoers` means you can't use `sudo`, of course. But creating a new group shouldn't affect `/etc/sudoers`. You must have done something else.

The way to recover from this (short of reinstalling) is to boot into a single-user root shell. From there, you can fix `/etc/sudoers`, and whatever else needs fixing. **Be careful** while you're doing this; it's very easy to break the system by manually editing system files like this and frankly you've already done so.

To get a single-user root shell, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/73442/22807). Quick summary: Hold down the left <kbd>shift</kbd> key while booting and follow the prompts to get a root shell.

Comment: The problem was with the disk, it was set on read-only and I had to fix that to be able to change the permissions of /etc/sudoers so I could add myself as admin, thank you!