# How to remove rick roll script at terminal startup?

Tags: scripts, gnome-terminal

I injected an sh script (https://github.com/jart/rickrollrc) using `./astley.sh` inject evil for a joke but now when I need the terminal I have to wait and then lets me do commands. How do I UN-inject the script so I can go on the terminal immediately?
Also I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all right now because I reinstalled Ubuntu.
Also,Journeyman Geek I’ve learnt my lesson to make a backup account.

Answer (score 3):

[From the readme](https://github.com/jart/rickrollrc/blob/master/README.md).

> Misc.
>
> If you've astley-overdosed:

```
./astley.sh stop
```

And also remove the script.

---

- As far as I can tell is that you need to remove the script from disc.
- A reboot will clean the process from memory OR do a `ps -ef|grep astley` and kill the process-id.

Comment: I've done that and it doesn't work

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this should only be running in the terminal you're running. Simplest way to fix this would be to boot into a livecd and undo it.Alternately, if booting into a livecd sounds like too much work you'll want to boot into [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73442/how-do-i-login-in-single-user-mode) (so you're root) and do the same thing.

To undo it, you simply need to go into your home directory from the other install, and remove it from your .bashrc, or better yet, work out from bashrc where astley.sh is now, and delete it (which is safer, since then you can edit bashrc from your own account, which avoids the risk of accidentally changing ownership to someone else)

And the next time you decide to do something this silly, have a backup account (and add it to sudoers) to fix this.

Comment: I can't find .bashrc and i tried to search for it

Comment: it should be under /home/username/.bashrc If you're using a livecd, look at your hard drive, not the livecd's filesystem